# how to give css link to HTML code?

Tags: html, css

my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="style" href="style.css">
    <script language="javascript" src="JS/CommonCharFunction.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    code
</body>
</html>
```

but my code is not working.i have to include style to html form
how to include inline css

Comment: Take a look here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: <link href="style.css" type="text/css rel="stylesheet">

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add css inline, you can try the style tag inside the head tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can include **inline style** by adding a style attribute to an element like so:

```
<body style="background-color: white;">
```

But I think you need to ask about how to add an **external style sheet**.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/style.css">
```

Of course you can also use the **embedded style**

```
<title></title>
<style>
   body{
     background-color:white;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="style" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script language="javascript" src="JS/CommonCharFunction.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    code
</body>
</html>
```

Pay attention to the `link`-tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

- the attribute `rel` must have the value `stylesheet`
- the attribute `type` must be given and the value must be `text/css`